# Using aspx controls in base class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got two aspx pages which are very similar and have various identical functions in the code behind. I'd like to create a base class which both the code behind classes derive from. Is it possible for the base class to access the controls on the aspx page. For instance:

```
class base
    inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Sub prepareScreen()
       'txtName is a text box on the aspx page
       Me.txtName.text = "George"
    end sub
end class

class codeBehind
     inherits base
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
          prepareScreen()
     end sub
end class
```

Somewhat understandably the code fails to compile with:

```
'txtName' is not a member of 'clsbase'
```

Is it possible to link the two together?

Comment: Check the answer again, I have added some more explanation.

Comment: Hmmm. If you want to set the value in both the pages, then you can use the FindControl way tho its not OOish.

Comment: But the UI related methods must be isolated in your page, and they shouldn't be made common. Here you want to set some text to a textbox on your page, so better duplicate the code and set it in both the pages, instead of making it common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the control as a property of the base class. Then in the ASP markup, use the CodeFileBaseClass attribute.

The [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) is no longer available.

```
class base
    inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Property txtName() As TextBox
    Sub prepareScreen()
       'txtName is a text box on the aspx page
       Me.txtName.text = "George"
    end sub
end class

class codeBehind
     inherits base
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
          prepareScreen()
     end sub
end class

<%@ page CodeFileBaseClass="base" inherits="codebehind" ...  %>
```

Comment: Couldn't use this as the pages were already designed (using a visual designer) and would have taken to long to set the positions of all the controls in code. Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you refactor your code, so that you have no need to do something like this.

One better idea will be if you create a virtual method in the base class, which you can override in your child page(s), and set the value of your textbox, as you'll have an easy access to the textbox.

Comment: refactor in what way? I am refactoring the code at the moment, trying to remove repeated code into a base class.

Comment: Thanks for you time Kirtan. The problem is that I want to set the value to George on two separate pages...

Answer (score 0):

You could use FindControl, eg.

```
TextBox txtName=FindControl("txtName");
```

which would find the control on the rendered page even though it was rendered by the descendant class. Though this is breaking the point of OO and separation of function/data somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtName")) to get the textbox. Be careful because if you use this base class else where the control might not exist

Comment: Not really what I want to do. I'd like the controls to be accessible 'natively' in both the base and derived class. The derived classes actually link to different aspx pages, they just have numerous controls in common.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your clarification:

You could Create a property:

```
protected TextBox txtName 
{
get{return (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtName");} 
set{Page.FindControl("txtName") = vale;}
}
```

Or Create a Virtual property:

```
protected virtual TextBox txtName{get;set;}
```

In this case you would have to override it at your main class

```
  protected override TextBox txtName{/*same as above*/}
```